# Dynamic number of columns and rows in a responsive layout

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, dynamic-columns

Lets say we have the following markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img src="..." alt="..." />
        </div>
        <!--
            And, possibly, many more columns, 
            which are printed dynamically using
            the PHP's foreach loop
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The resulting markup contains only one row and lots of columns. However, this is not useful at all: the grid is supposed to have 2 columns on extra small screens, 3 columns on medium screens and 4 columns on large screens, with a separate row for each collection of columns.

The above technique, though, produces markup that is not semantic and problems begin to emerge whenever one decides that he/she wants to separate ***rows of columns*** with a border.

If the layout was static (non-responsive), I could simply output a separate row after every X image(column) in the `foreach` loop, but this obviously doesn't work for responsive layouts.

The responsive approach seems to introduce more problems than I originally anticipated, because the server side can not distinguish whether the user has resized his browser window or not (and reload the columns with a different markup and number of rows accordingly). Making AJAX calls for this would be overkill and I don't really want to use JQuery to rewrap columns based on screen width, which leaves me at the mercy of nasty CSS hacks.

Is there a proper way to accomplish this?

EDIT: There *is* a way to do this, but it's also not the preferred one: output several grids with a different number of columns and show each of them using media queries. Although this is a possibility, I would never want to do this, because it produces bad markup *and* it's possibly bad for SEO as well.

EDIT 2:
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Multiple rows]

However, I also need to do this dynamically for *each screen size*.

EDIT: 3:
Here's how the layout should behave on different screen sizes:

[image: Different layout]

This seems to be difficult to achieve on a responsive layout. **The reason I need to have separate rows** is because I want each row to have a `border-bottom` CSS property. I can currently add such a separator using the `:after` CSS pseudo element on every nth column in the grid, but the CSS for such a separator is quite ugly (the separator needs to go full-width and since the pseudo element is a child of the column, I'm using absolute positioning in this case):

```
&:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 420%;
   height: 1px;
   left: -160%;
   background-color: black;
}
```

Is the above CSS the right way to do it? How else can I achieve this?

Comment: What's not semantic? The use of multiple DIVs? Perhaps a visual representation of what you are trying to achieve would allow us to better understand the visuals and the related issues you are having.

Comment: What's not clear? I've described the problem in detail.

Comment: Is your content flowing through the columns? Like a magazine or newspaper article?

Comment: I have a number of images. I want to show them in a grid, so I use foreach in my template to echo them out. Each image goes into a div with a `col-xx-y` class. This works well for any screen size. However, I need to add a border *after each row of columns*. This means that the borders would have to change places in different screen widths.

Comment: Assuming I've read what you're trying to achieve correctly, you're making this far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I'm fully aware of this. Querying the server multiple times is precisely what I'm trying to avoid. Let me give you an example. Lets say I have a grid which displays two columns on small screens and 3 columns on medium screens. How could I add a separator that separates each row of columns/images for every screen size? If I add a separator for every 2 images in my grid, it would work well in a mobile layout, but this wouldn't look good on medium screens (where I'd have to a add a separator for every 3 images, since a "row" contains 3 columns now).

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you include a visual for how you want this to behave on the different screesizes?

Comment: It seems that I either have a wrong understanding of the general practice, or I have difficulties getting my point across. I'll update my question with visual aids soon.

Comment: @Shawn I've edited my question once more. I hope it's clear this time.

Comment: right. if you combine the visible/hidden helper classes with a div styled with border bottom, it should work. I'll write it out and paste some code.

Comment: I can see only two outcomes in this: either I use additional markup (hidden separator divs that I display based on different screen sizes, not really great as far as markup semantics are taken into account) or I use CSS pseudo elements with ugly-looking CSS code. What would be the preferred way?

Comment: Those are two options yes. Maybe neither is perfect, but I think you will get frustrated if you aren't flexible with HOW you achieve what you want.

Comment: Hmm. Well, you could write it up as an answer anyway and I'll mark it as accepted, since you were the one who suggested doing it. :) I'll probably add hidden separator divs after each of my columns and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.hidden/.visible` helper classes combined with a `.clearfix` with divider/border-bottom styling. It gets a little complex because you'll use a different divider div every 2nd, 3rd and 4th `.col`, and then even more because you'll combine them every 4th, 6th, 12th, etc (where common denominators meet up).

Here is a DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/sEAH6qXHiI

```
<div class="row border">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <!-- every 2nd col -->
    <div class="visible-xs visible-sm clearfix divider"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <!-- every 3rd col -->
    <div class="visible-md clearfix divider"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <!-- and every 4th col -->
    <div class="visible-xs visible-sm visible-lg clearfix divider"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <!-- every 6th col -->  
    <div class="visible-xs visible-sm clearfix divider"></div>
    <div class="visible-md clearfix divider"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Good luck!